# Why is my html/ CSS grid in a grid not working?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make a input form in a grid that's in another grid, but it is not working. I've looked up how to make css grids so many times, but I can't figure out what I' doing wrong. The entire page gets stuck in the first grid box. I want to know if I am properly using the right location for implementing the grid or if its maybe a problem with how I put the grid class/id in

I am new to html/ CSS so please let me know if there are other problems.
(Other than the indentation it got messed up when I copy pasted I tried to fix it)

```
<!Doctype html>
 <lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Form</title>
   <style>
    #grid {
           display: grid;
           grid-template-columns: 160px auto auto auto;
           grid-template-rows: 150px auto 100px;
       grid-template-areas:
       "h h h h"
       "n g g g"
       "f f f f";
       }
    #ingrid {
       grid-area: g;
           display: grid;
           grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
           grid-template-rows: auto;
       grid-template-areas:
       "l m r";
       }
    #header {
       grid-area: h;
           background-color: #DBA3EE;
       color: #FFF; 
           line-height: 250%; 
       font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; 
       font-weight: bold;
           font-size: 72px;
       text-indent:20px;
       }
    #nav {
           grid-area: n;
           background-color: #15394F;
       color: #FFF; 
       font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; 
       font-weight: bold;
           font-size: 25px;
       text-indent:2px;
       padding: 8px;
       }
   .form {
        grid-area: g;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    }
   .inform {
        grid-area: l;
    grid-area: m;
    grid-area: r;
        }
   .midform {
        grid-area: m;
        }
   .rightform {
        grid-area: r;
        }
   .leftform {
        grid-area: l;
        }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body id="grid">
   <div id="header">HEADER</div>
   <div id="nav">Home<br>Main<br>Form<br></div>
   
    <form class="form">
     
     <div class="inform">
      <div class="midform">How would you like to be contact? <br>
       <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email" checked="checked"> email <br>
       <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone" > phone <br></div>
          <div class="midform">Which course(s) are you registering? <br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="course" value="ACS-1805" >ACS-1805<br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="course" value="ACS-1809" >ACS-1809<br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="course" value="ACS-1903" >ACS-1903<br></div>
       
      <div class="midform">Payment Method: <input list="paymenttype" name="paymenttype"><br>
       <datalist id="paymenttype">
        <option value="Debit">
        <option value="MasterCard">
        <option value="VISA">
       </datalist></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="inform">
      <div class="midform">Special Request<br>
       <textarea name="comments" id="sptextarea"></textarea><br></div>
       
      <div class="leftform">
       <div>Rate Your Previous</div>
       <div>Experience (with 10 is</div>
       <div>the best): </div>
      </div>
      
       <div class="midform">
        <div>0<input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="5">10<br>
        </div>
       </div>
      
           <div class="midform"><button type="submit">Submit</button>
           <button type="reset">Reset</button></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `#grid` from the body and wrap it around your other elements instead. I've also removed `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` from your form to make it remove unneeded spacing. Like this:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 160px auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 150px auto 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "h h h h" "n g g g" "f f f f";
}

#ingrid {
  grid-area: g;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "l m r";
}

#header {
  grid-area: h;
  background-color: #DBA3EE;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 250%;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 72px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

#nav {
  grid-area: n;
  background-color: #15394F;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-indent: 2px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.form {
  grid-area: g;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.inform {
  grid-area: l;
  grid-area: m;
  grid-area: r;
}

.midform {
  grid-area: m;
}

.rightform {
  grid-area: r;
}

.leftform {
  grid-area: l;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="header">HEADER</div>
  <div id="nav">Home<br>Main<br>Form<br></div>

  <form class="form">

    <div class="inform">
      <div class="midform">How would you like to be contact? <br>
        <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email" checked="checked"> email <br>
        <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone"> phone <br></div>
      <div class="midform">Which course(s) are you registering? <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="course" value="ACS-1805">ACS-1805<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="course" value="ACS-1809">ACS-1809<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="course" value="ACS-1903">ACS-1903<br></div>

      <div class="midform">Payment Method: <input list="paymenttype" name="paymenttype"><br>
        <datalist id="paymenttype">
             <option value="Debit">
             <option value="MasterCard">
             <option value="VISA">
            </datalist></div>
    </div>

    <div class="inform">
      <div class="midform">Special Request<br>
        <textarea name="comments" id="sptextarea"></textarea><br></div>

      <div class="leftform">
        <div>Rate Your Previous</div>
        <div>Experience (with 10 is</div>
        <div>the best): </div>
      </div>

      <div class="midform">
        <div>0<input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="5">10<br>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="midform"><button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```